# Query slow when using function in the WHERE clause

Tags: postgresql, performance, functions, postgresql-12, query-performance

This is fast (49ms):

```
v_cpf_numerico := ext.uf_converte_numerico(new.nr_cpf);

select cd_cliente into v_cd_cliente
from central.cliente where nr_cpf_cnpj = v_cpf_numerico;
```

This is slow (15 seconds):

```
select cd_cliente into v_cd_cliente
from central.cliente where nr_cpf_cnpj = ext.uf_converte_numerico(new.nr_cpf);
```

Function:

```
create or replace function ext.uf_converte_numerico(_input varchar(30)) returns bigint
as
$$
begin
    _input := regexp_replace(_input, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g');

    if _input = '' then
        return null;
    end if;

    return cast(_input as bigint);
end
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I am using PostgreSQL 12.
Why is the second variant slow?

Comment: Try to convert that to a `language sql` function that is defined as `immutable`

Comment: You must have nested functions here.  Otherwise, ":=" doesn't make any sense in your first "query", and the table "new" does not exist in your second query.  If Laurenz's answer doesn't work, then you need to show us the full context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this simplified equivalent:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION ext.uf_converte_numerico(_input varchar(30))
  RETURNS bigint LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE PARALLEL SAFE AS
$func$
SELECT NULLIF(regexp_replace(_input, '[^0-9]+', '', 'g'), '')::bigint;
$func$;
```

- [`IMMUTABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html), because it *is*, and for the reasons [Laurenz explained](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/251715/3684).
- [`PARALLEL SAFE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/parallel-safety.html) in Postgres 10 or later, because it *is*. Without the label, functions default to `PARALLEL RESTRICTED`, which disables parallel queries. This may or may not affect the query on display. But the 15 seconds you reported indicate you are operating on big tables. So it can make a *huge* difference in other queries.
- [`LANGUAGE SQL`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-sql.html) to enable [function inlining](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Inlining_of_SQL_functions), which won't matter much for the query on display (after you labelled it `IMMUTABLE`), but will simplify query plans and improve overall performance.
- [`NULLIF`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) as minor simplification.

Aside: your input is `varchar(30)`, which still allows *out of range* errors for `bigint`. Either consider `varchar(18)` to be sure. Or just make it `text` to remove the ineffective restriction.

Answer (score 3):

Since the function is `VOLATILE` (by default), PostgreSQL doesn't know that it will return the same value for every row in `central.cliente`, so it is evaluated repeatedly.

Set the volatility to `IMMUTABLE` and PostgreSQL knows that it has to be evaluated only once:

```
ALTER FUNCTION ext.uf_converte_numerico(varchar(30)) IMMUTABLE;
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first case you are using pre-calculated value `(v_cpf_numerico)`.

And in the second case value is calculated for each row in `central.cliente` during select.

Comment: But it should't since it can be evaluated first.