# Having md5(NULL) return a non-NULL value in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, functions, datatypes

I have a table with the structure `(content_md5 UUID, content TEXT)`, where I'd like to use `content_md5` (which is the value of `md5(content)`) as the primary key, and use it as a foreign key in other tables.

This is a "static" table, where the content (some largish documents) would be referred to by their `md5` value for simplicity, and to prevent duplication in the table (which wouldn't be a given with a simple `SERIAL` PKEY).

However, `content` can be `NULL`, which is different from an empty value to declare a non-existing content field in the referencing table.
Since `md5(NULL)` returns `NULL`, and `NULL` is not allowed in a primary key constraint, I'd like to have a way of having `md5(NULL)` return all zeros instead of `NULL`.

Example:

```
-- setup
CREATE TABLE example (content_md5 UUID PRIMARY KEY, content TEXT);
CREATE TABLE test (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, tags TEXT, content_md5 UUID REFERENCES example(content_md5) ON DELETE RESTRICT);
INSERT INTO  example VALUES ('00000000000000000000000000000000'::uuid, NULL);

-- usage
INSERT INTO example VALUES (md5('some text')::uuid, 'some text');
INSERT INTO test (tags, content_md5) VALUES ('some content defining tags', md5('some text')::uuid);

SELECT tags, content FROM test LEFT JOIN example USING (content_md5);

-- QUESTION: Having an md5-like function to return zero-filled "md5"/uuid?
INSERT INTO example VALUES (md5(NULL)::uuid, NULL); -- ignored, because already existing record
INSERT INTO test (tags, content_md5) VALUES ('non-existing-document', md5(NULL)::uuid);
```

Is it possible to somehow cast the returned value to a zero-filled string, create a custom function based on `md5()` which replaces `NULL` with `00000000000000000000000000000000`, or some other way to achieve this result?

/edit: Or perhaps I don't need any `NULL` values in this table, and can just set the referencing foreign key column to `NULL` to achieve the same result?

Comment: But won't `00000000000000000000000000000000` become a duplicate after the second `NULL` value - and therefore won't be able to serve as a PRIMARY KEY?

Comment: @Vérace, as the PKEY, my intent is for it to always be the only zero-filled row to reference a content value of `NULL`. (The PKEY column is UNIQUE).

Comment: Why would you have a user passing in a null value to this function and expect an md5 hash to be returned? If you have an undefined value shouldn't the resulting hash also be undefined? Also, it should be noted that the returned value is a text string not a uuid

Comment: Yes to the last sentence. In a normal db design, the "no content" would be represented by having no corresponding row in the contents table, and the referencing column being null. OTOH having a single dummy row to represent lack of contents is unusual and would lead to cumbersome queries too.

Comment: @DanielVérité, thanks! That's probably the better solution to my case, and eliminates the need for any "`NULL`" rows in the contents table, custom functions and the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest this alternative design:

```
-- setup
CREATE TABLE example (content_id serial PRIMARY KEY, content text);
CREATE TABLE test (id serial PRIMARY KEY, tags TEXT, content_id int REFERENCES example);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example ((md5(content)::uuid)) INCLUDE (content_id); -- !

-- usage
INSERT INTO example(content) VALUES (NULL);        -- allowed multiple times
INSERT INTO example(content) VALUES ('some text');

INSERT INTO test (tags, content_id)
SELECT 'some content defining tags', content_id
FROM   example
WHERE  md5(content)::uuid = md5('some text')::uuid;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=561efc18ff198c356aaecb68ab3ece87)*

#### Major points

Use a serial column (`content_id`) as surrogate PK of table `example` - and as FK reference everywhere. 4 bytes instead of 16.

Enforce uniqueness with a unique index on the expression `md5(example)::uuid`. Be aware that hash collisions are possible (even if very unlikely while your table isn't huge).

While being at it, add the `serial` PK column to the index with an `INCLUDE` clause (Postgres 11 or later) to make it a covering index for fast index-only lookup.

As opposed to a PK column, this allows `NULL`, and `NULL` is not considered to be a duplicate of `NULL`, which should cover your use case. See:

- [Allow null in unique column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20154518/939860)

In Postgres 10 or older don't add `content_id` to the index. Then you don't get index-only scans, of course:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example ((md5(content)::uuid));
```

**Unless** you want to allow only a single instance of NULL, which could be enforced with a function like you posted (introducing the risk of a collision - even if unlikely) or a tiny partial index *in addition* to the one above:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ON example (content_id)
WHERE md5(content)::uuid IS NULL;
```

See:

- [Create unique constraint with null columns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8289253/939860)

Do not store the md5 value as table column (redundantly) at all.

---

**If** you want to keep using the function you posted in [your answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/253110/3684), consider optimizing it:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pg_temp.md5zero(data text)
  RETURNS uuid PARALLEL SAFE IMMUTABLE LANGUAGE sql AS
$func$
SELECT COALESCE(md5(data)::uuid, '00000000000000000000000000000000')
$func$
```

Faster, and can be inlined. See:

- [Query slow when using function in the WHERE clause](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251709/query-slow-when-using-function-in-the-where-clause/251727#251727)

Comment: I can't use the `INCLUDE` clause until I manage to upgrade the cluster (still 9.6), but this looks great. Also many thanks for optimizing my function, I learned a lot from this.

Comment: @nyov: I addressed that above. And I improved my index suggestion. Better keep a complete index *in addition* to the tiny index enforcing unique null.

Answer (score 1):

Your request sort of breaks the concept of primary keys--you want your primary key to be dependent upon another column (why not make that other column--`content` in your case--the primary key?), and yet at the same time you want that derivative column to be unique.  It's possible to have this setup, but the design lends itself to confusion (i.e., future DBAs/developers will need to try to decipher what your design decisions were).

Also, `md5()` doesn't return a `UUID` type (though I suppose you intend to cast into `UUID`).

That said, I think you can use `COALESCE()` along with a sequence:

```
edb=# create sequence abc_seq;
CREATE SEQUENCE
edb=# create table abc (content_md5 text primary key, content text);
CREATE TABLE
edb=# insert into abc values (md5(coalesce('mycontent',nextval('abc_seq')::text)),'mycontent');
INSERT 0 1
edb=# insert into abc values (md5(coalesce(null,nextval('abc_seq')::text)),null);
INSERT 0 1
edb=# select * from abc;
           content_md5            |  content  
----------------------------------+-----------
 c8afdb36c52cf4727836669019e69222 | mycontent
 c4ca4238a0b923820dcc509a6f75849b | 
(2 rows)
```

Please also be aware that you can't set a `DEFAULT` on `content_md5` because of the following:

```
edb=# create table abc (content_md5 text primary key default md5(coalesce(content,nextval('abc_seq')::text)), content text);
ERROR:  cannot use column references in default expression
```

Comment: `md5()` doesn't return a `UUID`, but it can be cast to it, since it's a 16 byte data type: See https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/115316/187993

Comment: sure--my suggestion to use `COALESCE()` and a sequence still stands

Comment: The `content_md5` column should always be the `md5(content)` value. Your example would create rows where the md5-value is based on the sequence number, which could clash with a content-value of the same value which is non-NULL. I must have explained this wrong, I'll update the Q.

Comment: If that's the case, it's not possible `md5(NULL)` is always going to be the same value, and you can't have a unique constraint/primary key and duplicate values -- round square doesn't exist.  Ideally, you should have a not-null constraint on your `content` column

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way to create a custom function which does what I want.
I'm not sure this is the best way to solve it, but it works for me, so here goes:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION md5zero(data text) RETURNS text AS $$
BEGIN
    IF data IS NULL
    THEN
        RETURN '00000000000000000000000000000000';
    ELSE
        RETURN md5(data);
    END IF;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- TEST: 
INSERT INTO example VALUES (md5zero(NULL)::uuid, NULL); -- ignored, because already existing record

-- ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "example_pkey"
-- DETAIL:  Key (content_md5)=(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000) already exists.
-- Time: 0.477 ms

INSERT INTO test (tags, content_md5) VALUES ('non-existing-document', md5zero(NULL)::uuid);

-- id |         tags          |             content_md5              
------+-----------------------+--------------------------------------
--  4 | non-existing-document | 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```